# Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot problems

Tags: login-screen

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 x64 on my pc 2 days ago and it worked fine until today. I also have Windows 8.1 installed. After I login, a blue screen appears and after a few seconds, the message appears:

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error
```

I've restarted it 3 times but it still appears after I login. Here is a print screen:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other problem besides the error message? Install all the updates and it should  go away.

Comment: Your screenshot looks like there is no Dash or Launcher on your desktop, only the desktop wallpaper as in this question: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a bootable for Ubuntu again(sd cart, dvd), then you can reïnstall Ubuntu. No problem to remove the used partition and remake it(if there is no important information on it).
I hope this helped.